# ASP.NET MVC 3 Views Always Red in IDE

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio, razor

For some reason in Visual Studio if i have some controller code like :

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View("SpecialView");
    }
}
```

SpecialView will be highlighted red despite me having a .cshtml file available at Views/Home/SpecialView.cshtml. The application will compile fine and work fine in a browser. If I right click and hit 'go to view' it will say the view can't be found.

Its more of an annoyance than a big deal. I am running VS 2010 w/ MVC 3 and the April tools update.

Comment: Are you using ReSharper? If so, try to disable it for a while.

Answer (score 3):

"Go To View" is work for only same name view and method pairs. If you have ~\Home\Index.cshtml you can open Index page with it. But not for "SpecialView" because it is only one of View method parameters. It can be many views right. suppose

```
swich (hede)
{
case 1:
return View("MyView1");
case 2:
return View("MyView3");
default:
return View("MyDefaultView");
}
```

"Go to view" try to go only method name. for your sample it will try to find Index.cshtml.